# Local variable inside a method, and assigning a function?

Tags: javascript, variables, object, return

I came across some codes that for me it looked confusing, although I looked in many places googling, I could not find the exact answer for my question. In hope to know what's going on with this code I'm here, asking if there's a good explanation for me, so I would not only know how to do it but, learn what it does as well!

```
var fun = {
  a_method: function(){
    var f = function(){
      alert("FUN FUNNY FUNCTION");
    };
    f.another_method = function(){ // in this line, is another_method local or not? Because like mentioned f is local; how about another_method after the dot?
      alert("this is another method inside my fun method");
    };
    return f; // this is a local variable, why another_method isn't local?
  }() // these parentheses, what do they do in regards to the function?
};
```

What does `return f` do? Why does `f.another_method(){function(){}}` become `fun.a_method.another_method()` <= these parentheses confuse me because if `f` is local inside `a_method`, likewise shouldn't everything else be local as well? Like `f.another_method(){function(){...}}`, or to even be clearer I want to know why the `.another_method()` with an `f` preceding the `function(before the dot) return f`. and goes passed to `another_method()`? To be called `fun.a_method.another_method();` and no `f` in there see where the confusion is.

`fun.a_method.another_method()` <= these parentheses confuse me
`f.another_method(){function(){}};`

I should call it this way, but I'm not right (why, just because the variable is local) and this is not how it works with JS:

```
fun.a_method.f.another_method();
```

Trying to understand why not the above instead:

```
fun.a_method.another_method(); // note that it is without the "f" when it's called, now why not or "how it became this way"?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var anonymous = function(){var f = function(){alert()}; return f}();anonymous();
var anonimo = {method:function(){var f = function(){alert("this is an anonimous function")}; return f;}()}
anonimo.method();
var why = {method:function(){
var f = function(){
alert("this an anonymous function because the function was declared from a variable, is this right?")
};
f.notHere = function(){
alert("correct me if I'm wrong but, f is variable declared to an anonymous function just f alone \"notHere\"")
};
return f
}()};
why.method.notHere();
var lastScenario = {
method:function(){
var f = function(){};
f.notHere=function(){
alert("this will not work if I don't declare f as a function")
};return f}()};
lastScenario.method.notHere();
```